# How to set Model for Strongly Typed View in Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor, strongly-typed-view

I'm trying to pass my model to my view in Razor. With the old method, I could define it at the top of the file (the model).

I did some googling, and thought I figured it out - doesn't seem to be working. I'm not getting any intellisense on the model.

**Top of the View file:**

```
@Model CodySolution.Models.PhotoModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Photography";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_master.cshtml";
}
```

**Where I'm using the Model:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked margin-top">
    @foreach (var cat in Model.Categories)
    {
        <li class="active"><a href="#">@cat</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Is this the correct way to define it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`@Model` prints the value of the `Model` property.

To declare the model type, use the `@model` directive.

Answer (score 20):

In case someone is looking for the exact syntax, here it is:

```
@model CodySolution.Models.PhotoModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Photography";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_master.cshtml";
}
```

Note the lowercase `@model` since uppercase prints the value of the `Model` property.